# cv2 and BGR2YCrCb not working with Python bindings

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Is anybody having problems with OpenCV 2.4 and converting images to the YCrCb color space? I am using the Python bindings and I can't seem to find whatever definition is used to convert BGR2YCrCb. Here are some things that I have been trying:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY # works fine
6L
>>> cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV # works fine
40L
>>> cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb # now the trouble starts
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'COLOR_BGR2YCrCb'
>>> cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCC
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'COLOR_BGR2YCC'
>>>
```

Does anybody know how to perform the conversion in cv2?

Comment: I looked cv2.cv.CV_BGR2YCrCb which gave me a value of '36'. When I plug this into cvtColor it now works, but I'd still like to know whatever the definition value is.

Comment: +1 Good question, actually. Couldn't find this information on the docs and had to check OpenCV source code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python, `COLOR_BGR2YCrCb` is called **`COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB`**.

Looking at `build/modules/python/pyopencv_generated_const_reg.h` revealed:

```
97: PUBLISH2(COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB,cv::COLOR_BGR2YCrCb);
```